# linked list struct in c with read txt

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, e-commerce

[image: pitcure]

I upload picture above. I ask question, how can I read from txt files to add linked list with structs. I try this but how can I declare for basket.txt and produce .txt

```
FILE *fp
char CustomerName[20];
char CustomerSurname[20];
int  CustomerId;
struct Customer *current = NULL, *head = NULL;
fp = fopen("customer.txt", "r");

while (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%s\t%s", &CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerSurname) != EOF) {
    struct Customer *ReadList;
    ReadList = (struct Customer *)malloc(sizeof(struct Customer));
    ReadList->NextPtr = NULL;
    ReadList->CustomerId = CustomerId;
    ReadList->CustomerName = strdup(CustomerName);
    ReadList->CustomerSurname = strdup(CustomerSurname);
    if (head == NULL) {
        current = head = ReadList;
    } else {
        current = current->NextPtr = ReadList;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Please include where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtile problem in your code: the way you parse the input file is incorrect:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%s\t%s", &CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerSurname) != EOF)
```

- you should protect from buffer overflows in `CustomerName` and `CustomerSurname` by telling `fscanf` the maximum number of characters to store into these arrays: use format `"%d\t%19s\t%19s"` for that.
- you only check for `fscanf` complete failure at end of file, where it would return `EOF`, but it returns the number of fields parsed and you should check for this to be `3`.  If `fscanf` fails to parse an integer for the first field, it will return `0` and the contents of all fields will be unchanged.  You will loop indefinitely adding the same new record to the list, until you crash when `malloc` will eventually return `NULL`, which you do not test.
- The `\t` character in the format string will match any sequence of white space characters in the file, not just the TAB character.  This may be different from what you expect.  Note that `%d` and `%s` both ignore leading white space characters, so the `\t` characters in the format string are completely redundant.

There are other issues, such as

- You do not check for `fopen` failure
- You do not check for memory allocation failure

Here is an improved version:

```
FILE *fp
char CustomerName[20];
char CustomerSurname[20];
int  CustomerId;
int res;
struct Customer *current = NULL, *head = NULL;
fp = fopen("customer.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file\n");
    return 1;
}

while ((res = fscanf(fp, "%d\t%19s\t%19s", &CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerSurname)) == 3) {
    struct Customer *ReadList = malloc(sizeof(*ReadList));
    if (ReadList == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for customer\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    ReadList->NextPtr = NULL;
    ReadList->CustomerId = CustomerId;
    ReadList->CustomerName = strdup(CustomerName);
    ReadList->CustomerSurname = strdup(CustomerSurname);
    if (ReadReadList->CustomerName == NULL || ReadList->CustomerSurname == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for customer fields\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    if (head == NULL) {
        current = head = ReadList;
    } else {
        current = current->NextPtr = ReadList;
    }
}
if (res != EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "input file has incorrect format\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
fclose(fp);
```